# Regex working in online regex tester but not in mod-rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Regular expressions being something very new to me, I am having some trouble using them to redirect links of the following form:

```
url/search/aaa.bbb?label=dasdsf32r%20sdFa
```

to something like:

```
url/search.php?keyword=dasdsf32r%20sdFa
```

My regex below works on: http://www.myregextester.com/ for example but when I put it in my .htaccess file, the redirection doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^url/search/aaa\.bbb\?label=([^\t\r\n\v\f]+)$ url/search.php?keyword=$1 [NC,L,END]
```

Comment: "doesn't work" What happens?

Comment: It means that no redirection is done. The url doesn't change and I get a 404 error despite using the flag `R=301`

Comment: Here you have `.htaccess` tester, I will show you rewritten URL as well as which conditions were met: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string (everything after the `?`) isn't part of the URI that is used to match the pattern of a `RewriteRule` directive. You have to either use `%{THE_REQUEST}` or the recommeded `%{QUERY_STRING}` variables, and any groupings can be backreferenced with the `%` symbol:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^label=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^url/search/aaa\.bbb$ /url/search.php?keyword=%1 [L,NC]
```

If you actually wanted to redirect (as in, send the browser to the new URL so that it appears in the location bar) then you also need to either include a `R` or `R=301` (permanent redirect) in the rewrite flags:

```
[L,NC,R]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. 
I actually don't want the new url to be visible so I am sticking with the `[L,NC]` flags.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}
```

if you want to parse/modify `GET` parameters, because `RewriteRule` does not contains them...

Additionally, you should use `[NC,L,R=301]`.

Comment: Could you explain why do I need to use it for this particular RewriteRule? Other similar redirections in the same .htaccess file work without using `RewriteCond`, e.g.:
`RewriteRule ^url/cat/([^\t\r\n\v\f]+)_([0-9]+)$ url/cat.php?id=$2 [NC,L,END]`

As for the `END` flag, it ends all redirections and prevents the rewritten request from being evaluated again.

Comment: Left side of `RewriteRule` does not contain parameters. So if the request is `http://site.com/path/file?paramter=value`, then in `RewriteRule` you get on left side just `path/file`